# How to include only some iterations in the div class?

Tags: php, html

Let's say you have this code

```
    <?php
     foreach ($feeds->channel->item as $item) { 
             if($i>=9) break; ?>
                <div class="grid-item" >
                  <img class="rss-img" src="<?php echo $src ?>" alt="">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="title"><a href= "<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a></div>
                    <div class="datepub"><?php echo $pubDate?></div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
    <?php 
       i++
       } ?>
```

What I want to do is to add a `<div class="more">` above `<div class="grid-item" >`, but only include in this div class the iterations from $i=3 till $i=9 in order to have a class of them.
How should I do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a straightforward case of a `for` loop.

Comment: But I want the for loop to start when $i = 3, not from the beginning.

Comment: That's exactly how [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loops work. You tell them where to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the neatest solution, but it works and you can use it:

```
<?php
foreach ($feeds->channel->item as $i => $item) {
    if($i>=9) break;
    if ($i > 1) { echo '<div class="more">'; } ?>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <img class="rss-img" src="<?php echo $src ?>" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a></div>
                <div class="datepub"><?php echo $pubDate ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?
    if ($i > 1) { echo '</div>'; }
}
```

Comment: This is adding the `div` for the first three elements, not the ones from 3 to 9.

Comment: OP specifically states he needs them from `$i = 3` to `$i = 9`, so either `> 2` or `>= 3` would be needed.

Comment: In this case, $i is counted from 0. Therefore, the condition "$i > 1" (i.e. starting from the third element) is used to mark elements 3 to 9.But OP can build any logic, if he meant otherwise.

Comment: Why put the more `div` inside the loop to begin with?